# Facebook opengraph insights api on specific post id from my app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I want to build a dashboard that returns more customized insights from the insights generated by app.

The app is a facebook connect website that users visit and view a list of products. They can post to facebook about that particular product by sharing a custom story that incorporates that product on their timeline.

When I go to the insights for my app, it does a great job of showing me all social impressions for all custom stories that were generated on my site.

I'd like to narrow that down even more for specific products.

My plan is to record the object ids that are generated by these actions and link them to a partucular product in my database.

I'd then like to create a new dashboard page that will allow me to login, request read_insights permission from me and then use that object_id:product mapping from my database to show how many social impressions where recorded for a given product's object_ids.

Is this possible? I've read alot about it but still haven't found the most elegant way to get a segmented report of social impressions per type of content that was posted.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation all depends on which platform you want your app to run on.

The first major component is you must have a Facebook developers account which is easy to signup for. Just go to developers.facebook.com and register. Takes like 2 mins. After that you will need to create your first app and add the correct domain name where your app will be hosted and what platform it will run on. (iOS, Android, Web, ect.) Once that is finished you can make your app public so you can use the Facebook API in your code.

For the app creation itself. The first thing you need to do is import the correct API for your platform. Which you can find a walk through at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/. Once the API is imported you must build a Facebook object which contains your app id and possibly app secret. If you're using JavaScript you don't want to use the app secret because it will be visible to the public.

Now that you have your Facebook object you must require the app users to log in and grant permission to your app. You can add extended permissions to your log in process by adding a scope value to the log in button generated by Facebook. Here is an example.

```
<fb:login-button id="loginBtn" max_rows="1" scope="basic_info,read_insights,manage_pages" size="medium" show_faces="false" auto_logout_link="true"></fb:login-button>
```

After the user is logged in you can now query information from the users account using Facebook Api calls to Social Graph. Facebook also provides a tool to help you figure out what information you can query. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Everything else you want to do with the app can be done by Facebook API calls. You just need to insure you grant the user the correct permissions before making the API calls.

API calls are a little different depending on which language syntax you are using but they all follow the same data model and return some array of responses which can be parsed using JSON or the standard array format. The Graph Explorer tool listed above will show you the output for your queries so you can handle them accordingly.

I hope this helps gets you started.

**EDITED**

Here's the implementation in JavaScript

```
function getMetric(){

// make the API call

FB.api(
"/{app-id}/insights/application_opengraph_story_impressions",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);

}
```

Here's the reference now that Facebook docs are back up https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights

application_opengraph_story_impressions will probably give you the total impression of all stories made by your app. I ran it against my Facebook app and it came back empty but I don't have any stories so it might work with your's. Also to note in the documentation there is an * by this metric and I could't find what that means.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the explanation. But do you know the exact api call that can get insight information for a particular post on a person's wall? The documentation only states that you can get insights on posts from pages or apps. Do you know how to narrow down on a particular post on someone's timeline?

Comment: What language do you want the implementation in?

Comment: I just need the javascript api call to get insights on a specific app post

Comment: unfortunately not, you can't use that call to query a specific object id that was posted by an app. I've read the documentation before, that's why I was looking for help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will because that's the only thing I read in their reference guide about it. It is an edge call which you might have to add {app-id} before it, and actually generate the story with the app. I would post a link to the documentation but Facebook seems to be updating the references pages and all the links are broken. I'll check back in the morning to see if I can get it for you.

Comment: yes, that will give me insights for all stories, however, I don't think it's possible to get info on one specific story. Btw, the * means that the metric is updated every 15 min.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that right now Facebook don't give developers ability to get insights about app custom stories.

Currently Facebook documentation has the following Graph APIs for Insights data:

- /{page-id}/insights
- /{app-id}/insights
- /{domain-id}/insights
- /{post-id}/insights **(where this is a Page post)**

So `/{post-id}/insights` won't work because custom story is actually user's post and others endpoints don't apply to your case.

As far as I know the only other option to access Insights is FQL. For that you'd use insights table in a manner similar to this:

```
SELECT ... FROM insights WHERE object_id = ... AND metric = ... AND end_time = ... AND period = ...
```

Now most likely this also won't work with your custom story posts (I don't have posts which I could try it on right now, so I can't tell) but at least it is not explicitly stated so in the documentation, so you should probably try it out.

UPDATE:
I wasn't able to get any insights data via FQL, although as far as I understand the following code should have gave me at least something (object id is for my page):

> SELECT breakdown, end_time, event, metric, object_id, period, value FROM insights WHERE object_id = 224981264214413 and metric = 'page_fans' and period = period('lifetime') and end_time = 1395597892

But it results just in

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

Facebook also has some pretty old bug report about similar topic: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/508088155954330/ where they confirmed the issue, assigned it, and... did nothing to fix it for 6 months.

In case FQL doesn't work, my suggestion to you is - use your own analytics code to **track the creation of custom stories and get the friend count of the users**. It won't show you the real exposure of the posts but at least you will see some data on which types of custom stories where posted more often and what was the maximum potential friend count that could have seen them. By the way - to make charting easier, you could use Google Analytics events for that.

Comment: can you give me an example of FQL that searches for number of social impressions for a given object id?